# AngularJS refesh show Blank page

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, refresh

I have a `AngularJS` Project, and when i click refresh inside the `gamesList` page i get a Blank page.

this is my app.js :

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ngRoute','superCtrl']);

app.config(routeConnect);

function routeConnect($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

$routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'/App/templates/home.html',
        controller:'navCtrl'
     })
    .when('/gamesList', {
        templateUrl:'/App/templates/gamesList.html',
        controller:'gamesListCtrl'
    }));
}
```

I run the application with http-server and when i hit the refresh button in the log i get :

```
"Get /gamesList" Error(404):"Not Found"
```

Also i noticed that in the chrome developer the source is changes:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Any idea for this problem?

Comment: Have you set up server to handle `html5Mode` virtual directories?

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean ? I didn't set up nothing

Comment: Well if you don't configure server appropriately then you can't use `html5mode`. See `$locationProvider` docs.

Comment: any solution found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know what causes this issue, just remove $locationProvider from your .config in app.js...

I removed the $locationProvider so issue is gone but i have to use

`http://localhost:8080/#/home'

But the '#' comes in the url...

Answer (score -2):

You need to configure your server

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode